# custom password reset api in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, bcrypt, laravel-5.7, laravel-authentication

by default the password reset token emailed to email is different from one being saved to database. I have used the `Hasher::make()` and `hash_hmac('sha256', $token, env('APP_KEY'))` to hash that and then compare that token to database but invain. what should i do to transform emailed token to database token or compare them?
I also tried

```
public function convertToken($token)
    {
        if (Str::startsWith($key = env('APP_KEY'), 'base64:')) {
            $key = base64_decode(substr($key, 7));
        }
        return hash_hmac('sha256', $token, $key);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the boilerplate code that's in the laravel repository?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this method? Are you trying to return a hashed value to send in the email or a hashed value to compare against a value in the database?

Comment: @apokryfos I am creating the api for the password reset. and the boiler plate didn't seem to work with restful api but with templating engine

Comment: @GeorgeHanson ````$token```` is what i have from the email that was sent to me from the password reset and i think after performing ````convertToken($token)```` i will be able to convert that token to what it is in the database

Answer (score 0):

The [Hasher](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Contracts/Hashing/Hasher.html) used by the Laravel default implementation can be retrieved with

```
$hasher = Password::broker()->getRepository()->getHasher();
```

You can then hash your token to add them to your database like this :

```
$hasher->make($token);
```

And you can check a token against the value stored in your database with this code :

```
$hasher->check($token, $databaseToken);
```

But why do you want to implement yourself what Laravel team has already done ? You'd better use Laravel default authentication, unless you do this for fun.

Comment: hi. the boiler plate didn't seem to work with restful api but with templating engine. Actually I have to take the emailed token and find the entry in the database with that token to validate it.

Comment: or email address sent to me just contains token. How am i supposed to deal with $databasetoken in this case?

Comment: You still can use Laravel boilerplate and change the default controllers to make it match your RESTful API. They are located at app/Http/Controllers/Auth

Comment: @AhmedNawazKhan As the Hasher::make() function does not give the same result each time, you'll need to retrieve the token first. You can associate the token to a unique column to be able to retrieve it, like the email (as Laravel does https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository.php#L120 )

Comment: this is not the case because without the api when u click the email sent link u are redirected to page where u have to put your email and new pass. so the actual query that is performed is through email and not through token. I can of api we have to find the entry inside table through token

Comment: so may be i need the email in that email sent link too?

Comment: Token is in a hidden input, token and email are both used to validate the password change

Comment: so I have to add email to the link that is being sent to the email box. if so how should i do that?

Comment: The generated link you include in the email will look like `https://server/reset?email=$userEmail&token=$token`

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: How is the token currently generated ? How is it currently stored ? How the email is sent ?

Comment: i just want to add ?email=example.com to link enclosed in the email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189552/discussion-between-adrien-and-ahmed-nawaz-khan).